# Are PERC 5/i RAID controller drivers available and easily installed on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, drivers, dell-poweredge

We are looking to migrate a Dell PowerEdge 1950 with PERC 5/i RAID controller from an aging Windows 2000 Server installation to a modern Linux distro, probably Ubuntu 9.04.

I have come across some [discussions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=279687) regarding drivers for these RAID controllers indicating that some users have experienced frustration on older versions of Ubuntu (6.06).

My question is, has anyone installed a more recent version of Ubuntu on a PowerEdge with this RAID controller?  Has the driver support/installation experience improved?

I don't mind having to follow these workarounds, but I don't really have a server that I can test on, so I'm trying to get a feel for what issues I might hit during my install so I can be as prepared as possible to resolve them quickly.

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu Server 9.04

Comment: @Brad Gilbert - Yes, and want to go 64-bit too, if that matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that 9.04 will have the PERC 5/i compatible megaraid_sas driver.  It's not a particularly new chipset by now.

Comment: Should note that most Dell and IBM (and possibly some HP) RAID controllers are rebadged LSI or Adaptec parts.

Comment: PERC 5/i is working very fine with Debian Etch.  I'm pretty sure it will work with Ubuntu 9.04.